# How to Fetch Coredata?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift4

I'm trying to Fetch Coredata `User` with the attribute `token` however I can't get it to work, as I get an error saying `Value of type '[User]' has no member 'token'`.  I have tried several fixes on stack an non seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
let managedContext = coreDataStack.managedContext
let request = NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
do {
    let users = try managedContext.fetch(request)
    print(users)
    print(users.token)

} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: `users` is an Array of objects of class `User`. So that array doesn't have `token`. You might want to do `print("users tokens: \(users.map{$0.token})")`?

Comment: @Larme Thank you that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, type of `users` is `[User]` so an array of `User` objects, so you can get to token of each `User` with:

```
let managedContext = coreDataStack.managedContext
let request = NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
do {
    let users = try managedContext.fetch(request)
    for user in users {
        print(user.token)
    }
} catch {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

or if you want to get last (`.last`) or first (`.first`) `User` you can just do:

```
do {
    let users = try managedContext.fetch(request)
    if let user = users.first {
        print(user.token)
    }
} catch {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access a specific user's token, you should set predicate on a unique attribute. E.g. if the unique attribute is (for example) uniqueId:

```
let managedContext = coreDataStack.managedContext 
let request =    NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User") 
request.predicate =    NSPredicate(format: "uniqueId == %@", uniqueId)  
do {  
let users =    try managedContext.fetch(request)  
  if let user = users.last {   
  print(user.token)  
  }  
} catch { 
 print(error.localizedDescription)  
}
```